# Making a `FlxSubState` that can be re-used without it crashing on the second `open`?

Tags: haxeflixel

Typically, when I want to open a `FlxSubState` that I have defined in my code, I will use:

```haxe
openSubState(new MySubState());
```

I have all of my create/add logic inside `MySubState.create()`

Which works fine, except, if there is a lot of stuff on that SubState it can cause a huge lag spike making the game 'freeze' before the substate is displayed.

If I try set a variable to my substate and re-use it, it works once, but then **crashes the game** when I try to open it a second time, because the substate is being auto-destoyed on close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when a `FlxSubState` closes, it is `destroy()`ed as well - removing all added objects, etc.

Also, since `new` and `create` are only called the very first time the substate is opened, anything you `add` there doesn't get re-added (and you don't want to have `new`/`create` called every time you open the substate, since that would not stop the lag-spike)

The solution is simple: in the `FlxState` that is opening your substate, there is a flag `destroySubStates` set this to `false` and the substates will not be destroyed on close.

...and how do you make changes to the substate between opens? You can use the `openCallback` in `FlxSubState` which gets triggered when you open the substate, after `create` gets called (if it does) and before the substate is displayed.

So:

If you want to have an updating FlxSubState that can be re-used to cut down on 'lag' when it is opened, here's what I did:

in my PlayState:

```haxe
override public function create():Void
{
  ...
  mySubState = new MySubState();
  destroySubStates = false;
  ...
}

public function openMySubState():Void
{
  openSubState(mySubState);
}
```

in MySubState:

```haxe
public function new():Void
{
  super(0); 
  openCallback = refresh;
}

override public function create():Void
{
  // create and add all of my elements
}

private function refresh():Void
{
  // anything that changed between last time it was open and now, update .text/etc
}
```

AND this cuts out the lag spike everytime you open the substate!

...just remember to call `mySubState.destroy();` inside your `PlayState.destroy();` to clean up properly!